# Navigating through Razor View Pages

Tags: c#, .net, razor

I have a Login Page in Razor Syntax.The same Login page has hyperlink for Register Page also.But when i am clicking on Register Hyperlink i am getting error 404 (File or directory not found).My project Structure is like , there is `Views` folder inside which i have `Shared` folder and `Login.cshtml` page.Now outside `Views` there is a `default.cshtml` page which contains link to open `Login.cshtml` as

```
AuthenticateAttribute.DoHtmlRedirect("~/Login", Request, Response, includeRedirectParam: true);
```

Now my login page contains a hyper link as `<a href="~/Register"> Register here</a>` .I have added `Register.cshtml` page inside the `Views`folder just like `Login.cshtml`.

I for the first time working on the Razor Sytax.Please help me where i am going wrong.Thanks.

Comment: A good idea is to use the `UrlHelper`, with this class .net generates the urls for you. In a razor view just write `@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")`. What you are telling .net is that the `Register.cshtml` is always in the root folder of your application (by setting the url to **~/Register.cshtml**).

Comment: @JoeJoe87577 Point here is that my application is not using MVC So no controller here to do the things.In this case how i should go?

Comment: sorry I missed that bit. The corrosponding url to your **Register.cshtml** should be `~/Views/Register.cshtml`

Comment: @JoeJoe87577 Now i am getting  `Forbidden:access is denied ` error..

Comment: It's hard to find the error without knowing your project structure...